# How do you start a chat? Or can you start one?

Tags: support, chat

I am new here so please be patient with me... I just want to know how one would start a chat room? Or if one even can? Are they only created by Moderators/senior members?

Just want to know so I am not the silly newbie...

Comment: I've never done it, but at the bottom of the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) page, there is this link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new. Does that let you do it?

Comment: I've used that before, yeah. It works.

Comment: @Jonah feel like answering?

Comment: Yeah it works! Thanks @anaranjada

Comment: Thanks for helping the new person find there way around!

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom of the [list of all SFF chatrooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=scifi.stackexchange.com), there's a button for setting up a new room:

[image]

That link goes to [this page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new), where you can create a room with whatever room title you like, associated to whatever SE site you like. (I think you can even set up a room associated to a site where you don't have an account.)

Once you've got enough rep - at least 1000 network-wide - you can also create a [gallery chatroom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms), in which only users you grant permission (plus moderators) are able to post, although the room and its transcript are still publicly visible.